# How to solve django TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django

[WEBSITE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYOFW.png)**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post

def minjuand(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte = timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request,'blog/minjuand.html',{'posts':posts})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('', views.minjuand, name="minjunad"),
]
```

**in settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I added my application to my `settings.py` at the end of `INSTALLED_APPS` and checked for typos. Why can't Django find my template?

I am developing with Django 3.1.4 and Python 3.9.0 on Windows 10.

[BLOGPROJECT STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqSPz.png)

Comment: You haven't shown a template file or mentioned one. Where does your `minjuand.html` file live? Can you provide your complete error message, with traceback?

Comment: @Yeon are you sure that this part ```os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'templates')``` is pointing to the right directory ?

Comment: @Yeon You need to show us the structure of your Blog app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to define additional template directories in the Django settings. All registered apps (apps that are in your `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py`) use a default templates directory `my-app-directory/templates/`.

Inside your app directory, create a folder called `templates` (all lowercase), place your templates inside this folder. So if you had an app called `blog` it would look something like this:

```
> blog/
  > migrations/
    > 0001_initial.py
  > templates/
    > my_template.html
  > admin.py
  > apps.py
  > models.py
  > views.py
> mysite/
  > settings.py
  > urls.py
  > wsgi.py
> manage.py
```

You can then use your `my_template.html` template in a view like this:

```
def my_view(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request,'my_template.html', context)
```

Note, we reference the template as if we are inside the `templates/` directory

Comment: this "context" thing saved my day. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should create the templates directory inside the folder containing folder of project and app. If you have done that, then `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` do this change in `TEMPLATES` in `settings.py`